Is it possible to pass some application-specific options from hypervisor to vm
I want to make a tiny linux vmware vm running a single microservice.
VM and service requires some options like IP address, TLS certificate with key, configuration file.
It there any standard way to pass those parameters to VM from hypervisor?
I have idea to make a second tiny hdd for vm to hold some configuration files. Maybe there is another way of passing custom options into vm OS like Docker does it?


I have idea to make a second tiny hdd for vm to hold some configuration files.

That is one of the mechanisms supported by cloud-init, a standard tool used to configure virtual machines in cloud environments. You would probably want the NoCloud data source; just prepare for example an ISO image with the appropriate configuration files, label the volume as CIDATA, and attach it to the virtual machine.

Maybe there is another way of passing custom options into vm OS like Docker does it?

Docker doesn't have anything to do with virtual machines. Because Docker containers are just processes running on your host, you have a lot more flexibility in how you share information between the host and the container.
